# Encounter `npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY` when executing `npm install`

Tags: npm, npm-install, babeljs, package.json

Recently, I study the ReactJS tutorial from a youtube video, link: https://youtu.be/MhkGQAoc7bc?t=2m45s, and I encounter many error when I run `npm install` in the `1-basic-react` directory. In `1-basic-react` directory, there is already the file `package.json`.

Content inside `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "react-tutorials",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Error Messages:

```
unbuild babel-types@6.10.2
unbuild babel-helper-define-map@6.9.0
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react\nod
e_modules\babel-preset-es2015\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties\node_modules\babel-helper-d
efine-map\node_modules\babel-helper-function-name\node_modules\babel-traverse\node_modules\babylon\lib\tokenizer'
npm ERR! error rolling back  babel-helper-define-map@6.9.0 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\re
act-js-tutorials\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-preset-es2015\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-prop
erties\node_modules\babel-helper-define-map\node_modules\babel-helper-function-name\node_modules\babel-traverse\node_mod
ules\babylon\lib\tokenizer']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'E:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\GitHub\\react-js-tutorials\\1-basic-react\\node_modules
\\babel-preset-es2015\\node_modules\\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties\\node_modules\\babel-helper-defin
e-map\\node_modules\\babel-helper-function-name\\node_modules\\babel-traverse\\node_modules\\babylon\\lib\\tokenizer' }
unbuild babel-template@6.9.0
unbuild babel-traverse@6.10.4
unbuild babel-helper-function-name@6.8.0
unbuild babel-runtime@6.9.2
npm WARN engine unicode-property-value-aliases@1.2.1: wanted: {"node":">=6"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.13","npm":"1.3.2"}
)
npm WARN engine unicode-property-aliases@1.1.0: wanted: {"node":">=6"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.13","npm":"1.3.2"})
npm ERR! Error: OK, write
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\
\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.13
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.2
npm ERR! code OK
npm ERR! Error: OK, close
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\
\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.13
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.2
npm ERR! code OK
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod 'E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-preset
-es2015\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\
modules\core.regexp.escape.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\
\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.13
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.2
npm ERR! path E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-preset-es2015\node_modu
les\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\core.rege
xp.escape.js
npm ERR! fstream_path E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-preset-es2015\n
ode_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\c
ore.regexp.escape.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! tar pack Error reading C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-2516\1466863728585-0.9564304898958653\package
npm ERR! tar pack Error reading C:\Users\Casper\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-2516\1466863728585-0.9564304898958653\package
npm ERR! addLocalDirectory Could not pack "C:\\Users\\Casper\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\npm-2516\\1466863728585-0.9564304898
958653\\package" to "C:\\Users\\Casper\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\babel-messages\\6.8.0\\package.tgz"
npm ERR! addLocalDirectory Could not pack "C:\\Users\\Casper\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\npm-2516\\1466863728585-0.9564304898
958653\\package" to "C:\\Users\\Casper\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\babel-messages\\6.8.0\\package.tgz"
unbuild babel-traverse@6.10.4
unbuild babel-template@6.9.0
unbuild babel-types@6.10.2
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react\nod
e_modules\babel-preset-stage-0\node_modules\babel-preset-stage-1\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-class-constructor-c
all\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\modules'
npm ERR! error rolling back  babel-plugin-transform-class-constructor-call@6.8.0 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'E:\Users\Us
er\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react\node_modules\babel-preset-stage-0\node_modules\babel-preset-stage-1
\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-class-constructor-call\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js\modules']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'E:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\GitHub\\react-js-tutorials\\1-basic-react\\node_modules
\\babel-preset-stage-0\\node_modules\\babel-preset-stage-1\\node_modules\\babel-plugin-transform-class-constructor-call\
\node_modules\\babel-runtime\\node_modules\\core-js\\modules' }
unbuild babel-runtime@6.9.2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     E:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\react-js-tutorials\1-basic-react\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: node `v0.10` ? You should probably get a later version at the very least. Node is at 6 now https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Everytime I install node v6.2.2 and run `node -v` and it shows me only v0.10.13. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you've got some kind of PATH problem.  At a command line, you can type `echo %PATH%` and look for multiple entries that point to a node directory.

You'll need to edit your path so that only the directory with the latest copy of node is there.  There are [instructions for doing this on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path) on other Stack sites.

One thing to be careful about: if you've installed global modules, they are very likely in the v0.10.13 directory tree.  Make note of them before you change anything with an `npm ls -g --depth=0` as you will likely need to reinstall these global modules once you fix the path issue.