# How to Get Perl to Automatically Look in Specific Directories for Scripts?

Tags: perl, activestate

I have ActiveState Perl installed on a Windows machine.

Now, suppose I have scripts, including one called `"SomeScript.pl"`, in this directory:

```
"C:\Example\Foo\Bar\"
```

How do I configure Perl to automatically look in that directory for scripts when it is passed a script path?

For example, from the command line, I can run...:

```
perl C:\Example\Foo\Bar\SomeScript.pl
```

...just fine.

But the following...:

```
perl SomeScript.pl
```

fails because Perl doesn't know to look in the `"C:\Example\Foo\Bar\"` directory. How do I configure Perl to automatically look in some specific directory for scripts when passed a script name from the command line?

Comment: This might help - http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: That link doesn't help. Setting the Windows `PATH` environment variable is only useful when a command is passed to the Windows shell directly, rather than in this case, which is a script filename being passed as a parameter to the Perl executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in at least some Windows Perls (I'm using Strawberry 5.24).

1. Add the desired path to your Windows PATH.
   Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment variables
2. Run perl with the -S switch.

   perl -S program.plx

All the usual headaches of managing PATH apply (e.g. the first file with that name gets run).

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! I tried to upvote you, but as a new user, I apparently don't have enough reputation for the upvote to count.

Comment: I think maybe there is an option to flag/accept it as the answer. I'm new too so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of perl, it's more to do with your `$PATH` variable.

If you are on the *newest* windows 10 you can add the directory to your `.bashrc` file by appending `export PATH=<your directory here>:$PATH` to the end of that file.

Alternately, you can also add that directory to your PATH via menus. [Edit Environment Variables via the "Advanced" section of "System Properties"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path).

Then restart your command window and you can run the script thus:

```
SomeScript.pl
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There's no `.bashrc` file since the shell is the Windows command prompt, not Bash. If you mean adding the script directory to the Windows `%PATH%` environment variable, I already tried that, and it doesn't work; Perl apparently doesn't check the Windows `%PATH%` environment variable when deciding where to look for scripts.

Comment: You can't do what you are asking. Only executable programs are searched for in the path, not parameters. Your script isn't an executable. Putting the directory in %PATH% won't do anything. If you really want to just set a variable `set MYFILE=c:\foo\bar\script.pl` then you can do `perl %MYFILE%`

Comment: it is possible to do it, see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path

Comment: Feel free to edit my edit of your answer. :) I was excited when I heard about having bash on Windows, but apparently my versions of Windows 10 have all been too old.

Comment: That http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path link is about modifying the Windows `PATH` variable, which is only useful when a command is passed to the Windows shell directly, rather than in this case, which is a script filename being passed as a parameter to the Perl executable.