# How to open atom editor from Windows command line option?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7, atom-editor

I want to run the **atom** text editor from the command line option in Windows.

I am using **windows 7**. There is an option to just type `atom .` from the command prompt and the current directory should open up in atom editor.

As I do that it gives me an error `atom is not recognised as an internal or external program`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Atom is not opening from the command line, try adding it's directory to your system's PATH variable: [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path). Calling Atom from command line should be the same in Windows 7 as it is in Windows 8 and Windows 10.