# How to use the built-in web server of PHP on a machine running on Windows 10?

Tags: php

I'm using a laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language** which is **64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor**

Previously, I used to install WAMP/XAMPP on my machine to use PHP and MySQL.

In case of WAMP **"www**"was my document root directory and in case of XAMPP **"htdocs"** was my document root directory. In these directories I used to put my PHP files and run them from my browser by entering the URL as

```
http://localhost/dir_name/file_name.php
```

But, now I've come to know that since PHP 5.4.0 built-in server has been provided by PHP, so there is no need to install and configure a full-fledged web server.

I referred the file from official PHP documentation :

```
http://php.net/features.commandline.webserver
```

But I could not get how to run the built-in web-server on Windows machine as everything has been explained in the manual is with respect to Linux operating system.

Also, please let me know where should I keep my PHP files that I used to keep in a folder under **"www"** or **"htdocs"** folder.

Also, guide me in accessing these PHP files from a web browser using this built-in web server like I used to do previously(`http://localhost/dir_name/file_name.php`)

Thank You.

I tried with the following command in to command prompt:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

but it gave me nothing

see below image

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? The page you linked explains it perfectly? (Run `php -S host:port` from your shell and it listens on that host/port while using the current folder as the document root)

Comment: @ccKep : It's been explained from Linux point of view and not for Windows.

Comment: It's exactly the same.

Comment: @ccKep : See the screenshot I added end of my question.

Comment: That just means php.exe is not in your `PATH` configuration and windows doesn't know where to look for it. Either specify the whole path (eg. `C:\php\php.exe -S localhost:8000`) or add it to your `PATH` variable (google is your friend).

Comment: @ccKep : Now tell me what should I do? That's why I asked this question.

Comment: [Windows 7 - Add Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path9), 1st answer - Sure, it's Win7.. but the steps are basically the same in Win10 (except for the "Advanced Tab" you use the link on the left saying basically the same thing)

Comment: @ccKep : It would be better if you could all these steps as an answer. It will help me as well as other community members.

Comment: Check this link for setting the PATH Environment Variable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537574(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I just remembered; Windows is kind of a bitch when it comes to changing the environment. You may have to reboot. It is possible to set the path directly in the console, but it will be forgotten as soon as you close it.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction for Linux shouldn't be much different for Windows in respect to this. You still need a console though and preferably the path to PHP in the environment.

You could try to open a console by pressing the Windows key, type `cmd` and press enter. In the console try to type `php -v` and press enter. If the console know where to find PHP, you should see the current version.

If that worked, move to the directory you want to serve using the `cd` command and then run `php -S localhost:8000`

That directory is now the document root for the webserver at `http://localhost:8000/`