# Can't run subl command in Cmder bash

Tags: bash, sublimetext, cmder

I followed the steps outlined here https://laravel.io/forum/02-24-2014-a-neat-way-integrate-cmder-and-sublime-text-seamlessly, which are:

1. Create a new folder called 'Sublime Text 3' in the '/cmder/vendor/' location. You should also see the folders /clink, /conemu-maximus5, and /mysgit.
2. Download a portable version of Sublime Text 3 from their website and unzip the content into the newly created Sublime Text 3 folder.
3. Then, in the aliases file under /cmder/config/aliases, add: subl="%CMDER_ROOT%\vendor\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" $1 -new_console:s75V

Now I can use the subl command in a normal cmd window, but when I switch to a bash shell I get the same error, 'bash: subl: command not found'

Comment: since I'm currently fighting this, it seems that the user_aliases file in the cmder config dir is not loaded when a bash shell is started like a typical rc file. bashing my keyboard on this right now, but the best solution seems to be launching sublime text through a hotkey. https://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you want to run some command directly in the console, you have to add the directory where it resides to the system `PATH` variable.  There is no need to follow the instruction given in the link you provided.

### solution

Find the directory where `subl.exe` resides and add that directory to system `PATH`.
[image]

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path) on how to set the path.