# Can't launch Jupyter Notebook from the command line in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

On a Windows 7 machine, I installed Python 3.8.5, `pip` using the `get-pip.py` installation script from [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/), and Jupypter Lab + Jupyter Notebook following the instructions [here](https://jupyter.org/install). When trying to launch Jupyter Notebook, I get the following error message:

```
C:\jupyter notebook
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is the problem? I verified that both Python and `pip` was successfully installed by launching the Python console and doing `pip -V`.

Comment: It's likely that the Python environment you installed Jupyter into is not included in your system PATH variable. Can you add this to your question?

Comment: Hi, how can I check this in Windows? I only that in Linux, you can add this to the `.bashrc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jupyter.org/install is general installation instructions, but assume some familiarity with Python, pip, and system execution path searching.

You need to add the location where pip installed jupyter to you system `PATH` environment variable.

To test this theory, try seeing if you have jupyter.exe in a folder similar to `C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts`.

Answers to [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400030/windows-7-add-path), explain ways to edit the `PATH` variable.

Screenshot example of editing user's PATH:
[image: screenshot example of editing user's PATH]

Comment: Thanks, how can I do this in Windows? I just realize that I made the transition from regular Windows to regular Linux user... oO

Comment: @david, I edited the question with a link to Windows solution, probably at the same time you were entering your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact condition but try this..

```
"jupyter notebook"
```

and if it doesn't work then you might want to add installation location to your environment variables.

Comment: or start jupyter notebook