# Simple way to convert mp3 to ogg then zip? (Python 3)

Tags: python, audio, mp3, ogg, audio-converter

I've got a folder of mp3's I want to convert to .oggs in a specific sample/bit rate e.g. 44.1k, 160 kbps.  And then zip them up individually to host online.

I put Python in the title because I enjoy using it but I'm willing to use any free software or apps as well.

Is there a library you would recommend?
I found this thread: [Python library for converting files to MP3 and setting their quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246131/python-library-for-converting-files-to-mp3-and-setting-their-quality) 
But it looks fairly outdated

What about for zipping files?
I found https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html which seems like zipfile.zipfile and zipfile.write would cover me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Decode the file with [lame](http://lame.sourceforge.net/).
2. Encode it with the [vorbis tools](http://www.vorbis.com/).
3. Compress it with zip.

Here without any option flags:

```
lame --decode input.mp3 intermediate.wav
oggenc intermediate.wav -o output.ogg
zip output.zip output.ogg
```

You can script it with Python or Bash or whatsoever.

Comment: Which OS are you using? On Mac Os X things can be easily installed with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), on Debian based Linux distributions via apt-get. On Windows I am not sure, maybe you really have to compile stuff manually...

Comment: I'm sure there's a trick to it.  But from what I saw the readme was talking about compiling and makefiles and I really didn't want to muck with that.  lame/oggenc is what most of these programs/libraries are using under the hood so I know you're right that it would work well.