# Convert any audio file to mp3 with python

Tags: python-3.x, audio, converters

I want to convert any audio file (flac, wav,...) to mp3 with python
I am a noob , I tried `pydub` but I didn't found out how to make ffmpeg work with it, and If I'm right it can't convert flac file.

The idea of my project is to :
Make musicBee send the path of the 'now playing' track (by pressing the assigned shortcut) to my python file which would convert the music if it is not in mp3 and send it to a folder. (Everything in background so I don't have to leave what I'm doing to make the operation)

Comment: About PyMedia  , I tried to install it, but it don't work because I'm using python 3.5

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the following the code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

wav_audio = AudioSegment.from_file("audio.wav", format="wav")
raw_audio = AudioSegment.from_file("audio.wav", format="raw",
                                   frame_rate=44100, channels=2, sample_width=2)

wav_audio.export("audio1.mp3", format="mp3")
raw_audio.export("audio2.mp3", format="mp3")
```

You can also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246131/python-library-for-converting-files-to-mp3-and-setting-their-quality?rq=1) for more options.

```
flac_audio = AudioSegment.from_file("sample.flac", "flac")
flac_audio.export("sampleMp3.mp3", format="mp3")
```

Comment: Thank you , but can the oydub export .flac ?

Comment: @Canapy Yes, it does.

Comment: @Canapy If it does, can you please accept my answer?

Comment: But I didn't found out how to make ffmpeg work can you help me and explain me how to install it please

Comment: Well, Thank you for your help it work I tried so many things before, I must be dumb, now it work ! Thanks !

Comment: @Canapy I am glad that it helped